# The most time VS Most time

Tags: grammar, quantifiers

Please, read the following sentences:

- Mary's father spends **most *(of the)*** time in the mill, where he works with his brother, Mario.
- Mary's father spends **the most time** in the mill, where he works with his brother, Mario.

---

These are my understanding:

**To me, the first is unquestionably right:** He may work from 9 am - 7 pm. Then closes the mill and goes home to rest.

**The second sounds a bit odd but has some logic:** He spends most of his time compared to other activity: Maybe he runs a bar, drive a taxi, etc.

Are both examples acceptable?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences are correct, but they don't have the same meaning.

The first means he spends more than half of the day in the mill. "Most of the time" means "more than half of the time".

The second has two possible meanings. One is that he spends more time in the mill than anywhere else. If he spends 5 hours in the mill, 3 hours at the gym and 4 hours at the bar, he spends the most time at the mill, but not more than half.

The other possible meaning is that he spends more time in the mill than anybody else. Again, it doesn't mean he spends more than half his time there.

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for. Great as always, Gotube. Thanks.

Comment: I think by default *The second means he spends more time in the mill than **anyone** else*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's definitely another possible meaning. I've added it in. Thanks

Comment: I just ran a Google Books search for ["he spends the most time in"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+spends+the+most+time+in%22). In *every* case where the intended meaning is obvious (and where the word ***in*** doesn't actually end the sentence), it always seems to refer to "more time than someone / anyone else", not "the greater part of **his** time".

Comment: @FumbleFingers My answer isn't wrong though, is it? There are (at least) two possible meanings, and I've mentioned both.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is fine as a standalone sentence (with **most of the** or **most of his**.)

The second would only work if the previous sentence had stated what Mary's father spent *part* of his time doing. In that case, of course, the subject would need to be **He**, since he had already been identified.

Comment: Got it. Thank you, Kate. Could you tell me if my reasoning is correct in both examples?

Comment: I thought my answer had explained that.